# Call a function from a class constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

I’m using this class, Note, and I want to call the class method `mapCoords()` but it doesn’t do anything when I’m calling it from the constructor. When it is called from the show() function, it works, though;

Is it possible to call functions from the constructor ?

```
class Note {
    constructor(aName, aPosX, aPosY, aIsTonic) {
        this.name = aName;
        this.x = aPosX;
        this.y = aPosY;
        this.xCoords;
        this.yCoords;
        this.radius = 15;
        this.isTonic = aIsTonic;
        this.mapCoords();
    }

    show() {
        this.mapCoords();
        ellipse (this.xCoords, this.yCoords, this.radius * 2);
        text(this.name, this.xCoords, this.yCoords);
    }

    mapCoords() {
        this.xCoords = map(this.x, 0, maxNumberOfScales - 1, margin, width - margin);
        this.yCoords = map(this.y, 0, 12, height - margin, margin);
    }
}
```

UPDATE :
Okay, the function is called correctly from the constructor. the problem is the map function (which is part of the p5.js library) which doesn’t do its job.
When call mapCoords() from the constructor, `this.xCoords` and `this.yCoords` are NaN. but when I call the exact same function with the exact same code from `show()` the coords are calculated correctly.

Comment: You need to create an object of the Class `Note` to see anything. Runs for me.

Comment: The `constructor` method of a `class` will only be invoked when we create an `object`/`instance` of it

Comment: @Albizia - ad Edit: You have to post more of your code. But I can tell you what is happening - some of these variables like margin, width, height etc. or even some others that can be used in mapCoords are null/undefined at the time you create new instance, but later on they get initialized.

Comment: @libik you’re right ! I was calling  `new Note(…)` before I was giving `maxNumberOfScales` a value. Cheers !

Answer (score 3):

It is called correctly, you can try to run it.

What it does mean "doesn’t seem to do anything"

```js
let maxNumberOfScales = 10;
let margin = 10;
let width = 10;
let height = 10;

class Note {
    constructor(aName, aPosX, aPosY, aIsTonic) {
        this.name = aName;
        this.x = aPosX;
        this.y = aPosY;
        this.xCoords;
        this.yCoords;
        this.radius = 15;
        this.isTonic = aIsTonic;
        this.mapCoords();
    }

    show() {
        this.mapCoords();
        ellipse (this.xCoords, this.yCoords, this.radius * 2);
        text(this.name, this.xCoords, this.yCoords);
    }

    mapCoords() {
        console.log('It is here, learn to use console.log :)');
        this.xCoords = map(this.x, 0, maxNumberOfScales - 1, margin, width - margin);
        this.yCoords = map(this.y, 0, 12, height - margin, margin);
    }
}

function map(){}

new Note('a', 1, 2, true);
```